# I cant import firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Hi I am trying in src>index.js
`

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app'
```

`

I am learning from a video. When the man in the video wrote this code, he wrote that it is being calculated next to him in green, but it does not write to me. and I think that's why when I try to pull data from firebase database I get the following error in the console

`index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Can anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your security rules do not allow anyone to read or write to your database. If you set your rule to true as shown below, it should allow you to write:

Sample:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /series/{document} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

To configure your Firestore Security Rules:

> [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/?utm_source=firebase.google.com&utm_medium=referral) > Firestore Database > Rules (Tab) > Edit Rules > Deploy & Test

In this rule anyone can read or write to your series collection. I recommend reading about [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to restrict access to authorized users only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your firebase firestore rules don't allow reads or write for the collection that you are trying to query from.

Goto Firebase console and modify the firestore rules
Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started